# Accessing a object property created in appdelegate from other class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created a class B (which is having a `NSString` property named 'userName' in .h file) and initialised it in appdelegate using a global variable named 'bObj'. But while accessing it from class A using

```
_appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

`self.appDelegate.bObj` (still here it is working properly) but i am unable to access the properties of `class B`.

so that i imported `#import "B"` in `class A`. then i can able to access the properties of `Class B`

```
self.appDelegate.bObj.userName
```

Now i want to know the implementation of accessing a property of class B without declaring its object in class A and directly accessing it using appdelegate is correct or not?

and also can some one please explain me why i am unable to access the property of class B from 
`self.appDelegate.bObj.userName` in `class A` without importing `class B` (**#import "B"**)

i am getting this error

**property 'userName' cannot be found in forward class object B**

Comment: I am sure you are creating the property as private. Make it public.

Comment: you can do that accessing `bObj` using runtime APIs @ runtime, but not like known class whose class structure is known. `class_copyIvarList` can give you all instance variable names of `bObj`

Comment: Can you access bObj.username from within the appDelegate?

What happens when you try to access username? Are you sure it's initialised?

Comment: @TapasPal i declared it as public property only

Comment: @PokeyMcPokerson i can able to access the username property in bObj from appDelegate, it is working properly. But the problem occurs only when i am trying to access as above mentioned scenario. if i am removing the **#import "B"** from class A then it is giving **property 'userName' cannot be found in forward class object B**